# CSS - Alignment issues using Flex property

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm creating div's using flex property. There are three grids in each row. The first and third grid should align left and right side respectively. But the center grid should align center. I have tried but didn't work. Also I have attached my code above.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.outer-grid {
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ff4040;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer-grid"> One </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> two </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> three </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> four </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> five </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> six </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have 6 boxes, not 3.

Comment: No..it should be like this, but the layout should be what I said. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

AS you cannot edit HTML, one more solution would be to make the box take up the relative width of the container.

---

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.outer-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 25%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #ff4040;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer-grid"> One </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> two </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> three </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> four </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> five </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> six </div>
</div>
```

---

If this is what you are looking for, I'll write the explanation here later.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. thanks

```css
.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.outer-grid {
    width: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #ff4040;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer-grid"> One </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> two </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> three </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> four </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> five </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> six </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.outer-grid {
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ff4040;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer-grid"> One </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> two </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> three </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> four </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> five </div>
  <div class="outer-grid"> six </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not resolving his issue. Please click on answer only after you've written minimal answer for the question.